# TensorFlow keras model fit() parameters steps_per_epoch and epochs behavior on train set

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I'm using a tf.data dataset containing my training data consisting of (lets say) 100k images.
I'm also using a tf.data dataset containing my validation set.
Since an epoch of all 100k images takes quite long (in my case approximately one hour) before I get any feedback on performance on the validation set, I set the `steps_per_epoch` parameter in tf.keras.Model `fit()` to `10000`.
Using a batch size of 1 this results into having 10 validation scores when reaching 100k of images.
In order to complete one epoch of 100k images of my entire training dataset, I set the `epochs` parameter to `10`

However, I'm not sure if using `steps_per_epoch` and `epochs` this way has any other consequences. Is it correct to use these parameters in order to get more frequent feedback on performance?
And also a more specific question, does it use all 100k images or does it use the same first 10k images of my training set at every 'epoch'?
I already dug into the [TensorFlow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.2/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) and read several different stack overflow questions, but I couldn't find anything conclusive to answer my own question. Hope you can help!

Tensorflow version I'm using is 2.2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it correct to use these parameters in order to get more frequent
> feedback on performance?

Yes, it is correct to use these parameters. Here is the code that i used to fit the model.

```
model.fit(
train_data,
steps_per_epoch = train_samples//batch_size,
epochs = epochs,
validation_data = test_data,
verbose = 1,
validation_steps = test_samples//batch_size)
```

> does it use all 100k images or does it use the same first 10k images of my
> training set at every 'epoch'?

It use all images in your training data.

For better understanding `Epoch` is the number times the learning algorithm will work through the entire training data set.

Where as `steps_per_epoch` is the total number of samples in your training data set divided by the batch size.

For example, if you have 100000 training samples and use a batch size of 100, one epoch will be equivalent to 1000 steps_per_epoch.

*Note: We generally observe batch size to be the power of 2, this is because of the effective work of optimized matrix operation libraries.*